# Display tags on the page coming from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

There is a site with posts that have tags. The site has a search for these tags, that is, you enter words / letters separated by a space and tags are displayed for you by matches. These tags can be selected and double-clicked to disable. When you enter words in the search bar, a query is sent to the database and a response (a list of tags) is received. The main question is how to more effectively display and delete tags that come from the server.
I did not find suitable JS libraries

There is a [demo](https://codepen.io/Wemaka/pen/rNKxJMJ) version showing what the search looks like. Don't look at the code in it.

Here is all my code that works with requests.

```
<div class="search">
    <div class="search__container">
        <form class="search__inner" action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get" id="search-form">
            <div class="search__input-wrapper">
                <div class="search__input-container">
                    <div class="search__input">
                        <button class="search__search-btn button search__icon" type="submit">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass"></i>
                        </button>
                        <input class="search__input-form" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Поиск..."
                        autocomplete="off" data-search-input value="{{search_input}}">
                        <div class="search__close-btn search__icon">
                            <i class="fa-solid fa-xmark"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search__controls">
                        <!-- there are buttons for sorting -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="search-content">
                <div class="tags-list"></div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
// parent of all tags
const tagList = document.querySelector(".tags-list");
// search line
const searchInput = $(".search__input-form");
// an array of all tags. perhaps it's better to make it a live array
let arrayitem = [];

let inputDelay;
searchInput.on("input", function () {
    let textInp = searchInput.val().trim().toLowerCase();
    clearTimeout(inputDelay);

    // waiting for the end of typing words
    inputDelay = setTimeout(functions () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: urlTag,
            data: { operation: textInp },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                // response = { "tags": [{name: "text", slug: "text"},] }

                function createTags(nameTag, slugTag) {
                    let tag = document.createElement("div");
                    tag.className = "tags-list__tag";
                    tag.style = "display: none;";
                    tag.innerHTML = `
                        <input class="tags-list__checkbox hidden-input three-pos-inp" id="id_${slugTag}" name="${slugTag}"
                        readonly tabindex="-1" type="number" value="0">
                        <span>${nameTag}</span>`;

                    return tag;
                }

        
                // if there are tags on the page now
                if (arrayitem.length !== 0) {
                    arrayitem.forEach(function (e) {
                        // if the tag that is on the page is not selected, then we 
                        // will remove it from the page
                        let valueinp = e.querySelector(".three-pos-inp").value;

                        if (valueinp === "0") {
                            e.remove();
                        } else {
                            // otherwise we remove the selection, then remove this tag 
                            // from response so that it does not re-create in the next cycle
                            let txtTag = e.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent;
                            e.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = txtTag;
                            response["tags"].splice(
                                response["tags"].findIndex((tag) => {
                                    return tag.name === txtTag;
                                }),
                                1,
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }

                // adding new tags to the page
                response["tags"].forEach((tag) => {
                    let newTag = createTags(tag.name, tag.slug);
                    tagList.append(newTag);
                    show(newTag);
                });


                arrayitem = document.querySelectorAll(".tags-list__tag");
                // sorting tags so that the selected ones are always at the beginning
                tagSort(arrayitem);

                // highlighting letters in yellow. we divide the user's string by spaces and look for matches in each tag
                arrayitem.forEach(function (e) {
                    textInp.split(" ").forEach(function (text) {
                        if (searchForMatches(e.innerText, text)) {
                            e.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].innerHTML = inserMark(
                                e.innerText,
                                e.innerText.toLowerCase().search(text),
                                text.length,
                            );
                        }
                    });
                });
            },
        });
    }, 200);
});
```

The functions show, tagSort, searchForMatches, inserMark and tag selection event are in the demo. Output and highlighting of 200 tags takes 0.2 seconds